# How to set RadioGroup setValue() function in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have a Radio group having radio buttons Male and Female.
Please see below code

```
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Gender',
    name: 'rbGender',
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    },
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            boxLabel: 'Male',
            name: 'gender',
            inputValue: false,
            //checked: true,
            id: 'radio1'
        },
        {
            boxLabel: 'Female',
            name: 'gender',
            inputValue: true,
            id: 'radio2'
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to set these radio fields when I am getting values from database of gender field Male or Female(true/false).

please see below code.

```
 if (rec[0].gender == true) {
     me.form.getForm().findField('gender').setValue(true);
 }
 else if (rec[0].gender == false) {
     me.form.getForm().findField('gender').setValue(true);
 };
```

how to set male female radio button by database gender field value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass an object, with the radio item name as the key and the value, like:

```
setValue({gender: true}) // will set the female as selected.
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1o8c

Answer (score 0):

**You can set value different way**

```
1)  this.form?.get('gender')?.setValue(true);

2)  gender: new FormControl(true, Validators.compose([
       Validators.required
   ])),
```